# SAGA Majority Filter output error

Tags: qgis, saga

I have a simple raster dataset (GRASS topidx) that has been rounded down, so all the cells are integers. When I use the SAGA Majority filter in QGIS, the cells are no longer integers. I have modified all the parameters with no improvement.

When I put the same dataset into ER Mapper and run a majority filter, the answer is perfect...every cell is an integer, and has the majority search area value.

Here is one example:

11 11 11

10 8  8

10 9  11

The majority is clearly 11 (the ER Mapper answer), but SAGA gives it as 8.972162.

I am using QGIS 3.14.16 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Although my dataset was rounded to an integer, it was still Float 64. The SAGA output is Float 32.

Saving (converting) the input to Byte or Int16 gives correct integers as output, although the data output type is still Float 32.

The answer to the problem is to look carefully at the data type, or the result could be wrong.